# Change drawing order in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers

I have two layers (street name and address numbers). I try to sort layers where street names covers the address numbers. Unfortunately I cannot success because address numbers will always covers street names if I change layers order also.
It is always same situation.

Why numbers (address numbers) will be prioritized over text (street names) layers?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

this is because your street name and address number are label.

Label are always rendered last (so on top of all layer) you can't have symbology covering a label.

But if you want to choose the label rendering order you may set 'Label z-index' for each layer.

[image]

Comment: How to use this hint when using rule based labeling and two different data layer?

Comment: I set Label z-index value 1 for address numbers and 35 for street names. Both layers has ruled based labeling. Nothing change from original situation.

Comment: I test it on QGIS 3.4 and the z-index work as expected (between different layer, in one layer with different rule and between layer with rule). If you want the street names below you need to set a lower z-index (the higher the index, the higher the label are drawn)

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.8 version

Comment: What is scale when using Label Z-value? Can I use also minus -values under zero? I try to set 10 to 100 for street name -layers and -10 to -100 for address numbers. It may help a little bit.